# Probability that last visited state is a given state

Tags: probability

Say there's $n$ nodes in a graph, labeled as $S_1, S_2, ..., S_n$. Let $p_{i,j}$ be the transition probability between nodes (i.e. it is the probability that $S_i$ transitions to $S_j$) with $\sum_{k=1}^n p_{i,k} = 1$ for all $i$. Also, assume that all nodes are visited with probability $1$ given infinite time (I think the condition that the graph is connected is enough for this, where an edge exists if the probability of traveling along that edge is nonzero). The question:

> A dot starts at $S_i$ and jumps around in accordance with the given probabilities. What is the probability that the last visited node is $S_k$?

I'll denote this probability as $P_{i,k}$. I'm interested in finding this probability for all $i,k$. This can be algorithmically computed for all $k$ at once (but not all $i$) in $O(n^3)$ by moving the dot from $S_j$ and then replacing $p_{t, u}$ with $$p_{t,u}+p_{t,j}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}p_{j,j}^mp_{j,u} = p_{t,u}+\frac{p_{t,j}p_{j,u}}{1-p_{j,j}}$$ for all $t, u$. This is the original transition probability plus the probability of it passing from $S_t$ to $S_u$ through $S_j$. Then $S_j$ can be deleted or ignored. I put Python code for this approach at the bottom. But I'm wondering if there is a closed form. The ideal answer to this question would have a matrix of transition probabilities as input and would have some way to get a matrix of probabilities of final cells, where $a_{i,k}$ in the second matrix is $P_{i,k}$.

I had the thought of representing this as a Markov chain, but I don't think I can because states would depend on all the previous visited nodes and the current node, which would make there be $n\cdot 2^n$ states, which is unreasonably large.

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

In the Python code, the example transition probabilities are given by $$\pmatrix{\frac{1}{9} & \frac{3}{9} & \frac{4}{9} & \frac{1}{9} \\ \frac{3}{9} & \frac{3}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{2}{9} \\ \frac{2}{10} & \frac{4}{10} & \frac{1}{10} & \frac{3}{10} \\ \frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} }$$

where the $(i,j)$-th element is $p_{i,j}$, and the output matrix of $P_{i,k}$ is $$\pmatrix{0 & \frac{499}{1984} & \frac{209}{806} & \frac{407}{832} \\ \frac{11}{50} & 0 & \frac{23}{65} & \frac{277}{650} \\ \frac{92}{225} & \frac{53}{288} & 0 & \frac{977}{2400} \\ \frac{19}{60} & \frac{41}{186} & \frac{287}{620} & 0}$$

Python code (it could be made more efficient, but I didn't optimize too much):

```
import numpy as np
import copy

def updateTransitions(current, transitionProbs, unvisited, n):
    #only updates unvisited nodes (visited nodes are irrevelant - no point in updating them)
    for entry in range(n):
        for out in range(n):
            if entry in unvisited and out in unvisited:
                transitionProbs[entry][out] += transitionProbs[entry][current]*transitionProbs[current][out]/(1-transitionProbs[current][current])
                
    return transitionProbs

def findProbability(current, transitionProbs, unvisited = None):
    #transitionProbs is matrix
    #transitionProbs[i][j] = probability of moving from i to j
    #precondition: transitionProbs[i][i] != 1 for all i, current not in unvisited, and all nodes visited eventually
    #returns numpy array with array[k] representing the probability that S_k is last node visited
    
    n = len(transitionProbs)
    if unvisited is None:
        unvisited = set(range(n))
        unvisited.remove(current)
    
    output = np.zeros(n)
    if len(unvisited) == 0:
        #current was the last one that was visited
        output[current] += 1
        return output
    
    #inefficient to copy matrix every time, but it's needed to prevent harmful changes in future calls
    changedProbs = updateTransitions(current, copy.deepcopy(transitionProbs), unvisited, n)
    
    for possibleNext in unvisited:
        output += transitionProbs[current][possibleNext]*findProbability(possibleNext, changedProbs, unvisited - {possibleNext})
    
    #to offset the probability of it going to the same node
    output /= 1-transitionProbs[current][current]
    
    return output

transitionProbs = [[1/9, 3/9, 4/9, 1/9], [3/9, 3/9, 1/9, 2/9], [2/10, 4/10, 1/10, 3/10], [1/5, 2/5, 1/5, 1/5]]
print(np.array([findProbability(start, transitionProbs) for start in range(len(transitionProbs))]))
```